# How do i draw a polyline in android studio for array of coordinates?

Tags: polyline

http://107.180.68.111:84/ZIGAPICleveland/api/Trip/GetAllShapes?Page=0

this is the api i got and how do i draw a polyline for this?

Comment: I don't how to draw for these many points

Comment: That's not my question. What have you tried, and what specific problem are you having? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Again, please read the link I previously posted. I will not ask again.

Comment: Dude chill, i am new to stack overflow

Comment: That is literally the point. I've directed you to a place that shows you how to ask, which you've blatantly ignored (along with the questions I've asked)

Answer (score 0):

here is the code, first get an ArrayList of coordinates from the above link using JSON parser then use this code

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                geodesic(true).
                color(Color.BLUE).
                width(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++)
            polylineOptions.add(coordinates.get(i));

        mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

here coordinates is the arraylist of location coordinates, mMap is GoogleMap object

Comment: How do i get array list of coordinates ?,there are too many , should i import the api(link) or type the coordinates?

Comment: you need to use JSON parsing

Comment: can you send me any reference or tutorial?